# Matching S22 with a metal plate at the output

Tags: soldering, high-frequency, copper

So assume we have a highfrequency device which has a missmatch at S22. Some of my colleagues solder a little round metal plate, placed on top of the signalpath it self (shortly before the SMA Connector) to improve S22 by 5 to 10dB.

My question is, why is this improving the signal that much?
Is it behaving like a capacitor? Does it depend on the resonance frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the metal plate is 'little', then it's behaving like a small capacitance.

If the connection has excess inductance, or in other words is high impedance, then this extra capacitance can form a low pass filter with the inductance to match it across the frequency range of interest.

Ask your colleagues how they knew *where* to add the extra capacitance. It may be that that particular assembly always needs a bit of extra C there. Or they may have measured the S22, and noticed some ripple, with a frequency that told them how far the defect was from the connector, and a phase that told them whether it was high or low impedance. They may have measured the S22 with a TDR, which basically does the sums of the last sentence for you. Or they may have been dabbing a bit of extra C around experimentally, to see if anything improved the S22 (it's not illegal and it's quick to do, I'm not ashamed to do it!)

Comment: That it behaves like a Low Pass is the thought that i missed. It makes noch much more sense. thank you.